# Call to a member function getTimestamp() on boolean

Tags: php, datetime

I got this error whatever format i changed, i have no idea what else causes of this. Can someone help me on this? My csv excel dateTime format is `yyyy/mm/dd H:mm`

```html
  $i = 0;
  $len = count($map_column);
  $insData = array();
  foreach ($map_column as $key => $value) {
   $i++;
   if ($key == 'dateTime') {
    $date = date_create_from_format('Y/m/d H:i:s', $row[$value]);
    $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp();
    $sql .= 'UNIX_TIMESTAMP('.$key . ') = "' . $timestamp . '"';
   } else {
    $sql .= $key . ' = "' . $row[$value] . '"';
   }
   $insData[$key] = $row[$value];
   if ($i < $len) {
    $sql  .= ' AND ';
   }
  }
  $result = mysqli_query($cons, $sql);
  $r = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
  $count = (int)$r['count'];
  if ($count) {
   return;
  }

  // pr($insData);
  $columns = implode(", ",array_keys($insData));
    $escaped_values = array_values($insData);
    $values = implode("', '", $escaped_values);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO hrar($columns) VALUES ('$values')";
    if ($cons->query($sql)) {
      echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
      echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `$date = date_create_from_format('Y/m/d H:i:s', $row[$value]);` is failing.... so what exactly is the value in `$row[$value]`? Does it match the format mask that you've specified?

Comment: [`date_create_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php#refsect1-datetime.createfromformat-returnvalues) returns false for an invalid date. You should validate the `$date` prior to attempting to execute a method from the expected object. According to your date example for your csv you should be using `date_create_from_format('Y/m/d H:i', row[$value]);`

Comment: @MarkBaker the format value is like this 2017-08-30 11:20:00 from csv file,

Comment: So your actual date from the csv file uses a `-` separator, but the format mask you're using has a `/` separator.... perhaps that is the cause of your problem!!!! `-` !== `/`

Comment: @fyrye already changed..but still cant...is there anything to do with the csv excel format?

Comment: @Sara you should validate the date is correct. `if($date) { $timestamp = $date->getTimestamp(); }` etc. But based on your response to Mark you also need to use `date_create_from_format('Y-m-d H:i:s', row[$value]);`